# Will this leak under ARC?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ivar

I have a question regarding how ARC works. I have started working on IOS recently, I have created my project with ARC, As per documentation, ARC would take care of freeing memory by keep tracking reference count. Consider I have picker view ivar, when corresponding view is popped it will get freed, what if the case I explicitly set to nil and create again like this...

```
audio_cap_picker = nil;
// Creat picker view.
if (audio_cap_picker == nil) {
    audio_cap_picker = [[UIPickerView alloc] init];
    audio_cap_picker.delegate = self;
    audio_cap_picker.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:audio_cap_picker];
}
```

If I do every time like this, will the memory get freed, or it will leak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code is fine under ARC. It will not leak.

Comment: And even you can remove the 'nil' checking, because it always will be 'TRUE'.